# How do I play a particular playlist with mpc?

Tags: linux, music, playlists, mpd

I am using mpd with mpc for all my music needs.

Now, what I want to ask is how to `load/play` songs from a particular playlist in mpc/mpd so that it only plays those song.

*For example,*

I created a `linkinpark.m3u` playlist file using `ncmpcpp`.Now I want to load this `playlist` in mpc so that it only plays the song which are included in the above mentioned playlist. Currently what it does is play all my songs at random.

**Output of lsplaylists**

```
ranrag@ranrag:~$ mpc lsplaylists 
linkinpark
Rock
[other playlists]
```

PS: No, gmpc or sonata based solution please.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## ncmpc

`ncmpc` shows the playlists in the `Browse screen` (<kbd>3</kbd>).

## ncmpcpp

`ncmpcpp` is quite similar to `ncmpc` maybe it behave the same.

## mpc

You can load (append) a playlist with the `load` command, so to play a specified playlist:

```
mpc clear
mpc load <playlist_name>
mpc play
```